# How do I enable the Indian Rupee sign in Natty?

Tags: 11.04

The new Indian Rupee sign, Unicode 20B9, is supposed to have been introduced in Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick. It is already the default currency symbol for the English (India) (en_IN) locale in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric. However, in Natty the default currency symbol, as displayed in the GNOME Regional Formats window, is still the older generic Rupee sign, Rs, Unicode 20A8. In Character Map I found that Unicode 20B9 is not defined in Natty, even with the latest version of the Ubuntu font. Without this definition, the symbol seems to remain unavailable no matter what the font. Is there any way to enable the new symbol?

Answer (score 2):

As a Indian, I am proud to share this

```
1) First of all Download ttf fonts for Indian Rupee Symbol.
Link to Download :- http://hiteshjoshi.com/downloads/Fonts.zip

2) Extract Fonts.zip. Using GUI or from Command. If You want to unzip file using command in Linux then unzip is the command (i.e. unzil Fonts.zip)

3) In Fedora and Ubuntu Double Click on .ttf File. You will get a Option in Right Down Side “Install Font.” Click on Install Font for all three .ttf Files one by one and That’s It. You are done.Below is the screen shot for the same.


Installing Fonts in Linux Using Font Viewer
4) To Test that Fonts for Indian Rupee Symbol is installed or not We will use Open Office. Lets Use OpenOffice Writer to test it.

5) Click on Application -> Click on Office -> Click on OpenOffice.org Writer.

6) Right now Indian Rupee Symbol can only be written in Three Fonts Which You have installed from Fonts.zip
You can use Verdana, Times New Roman and Arial to Type Indian Rupee Symbol On Linux. Below is the screen shot.


Selecting Fonts for Indian Rupee from OpenOffice Writer
7) Now Press a (~) key exact above TAB key without bracket. You dont’t have to combine ~ key with any key combination like CTRL ALT SHIFT. Nothing Just Press the ~ key and you will able to see a Indian Rupee Symbol into OpenOffice Writer. Below is the image for ~ key on Keyboard.



Note :- Still I have not test this fonts into RHEL and Ubuntu but it should work. Because I don’t use Ubuntu as much so guys if you are having any problems or doubts let me know with your errors and doubts.
```

Thanks to Hitesh Joshi Blog and Layman Linux.

http://www.tejasbarot.com/2010/08/03/installing-new-indian-rupee-symbol-in-linux-fedora-rhel-ubuntu/

This is the link, it is very detailed explanation with screenshots.

Comment: It's appreciated if you provide more than just a link to the answer. You could copy and post some of the instructions from the source article and leave a link for further reference.

Comment: Would be great if you could edit this answer to provide more instructions :)

Comment: That's fine, but I'm not looking for a Rupee symbol to insert into a document. I want Ubuntu to use it by default by incorporating it into the system's locale itself, as in Oneiric. The currency symbol is specified in /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IN in the LC_MONETARY section, but editing this file does nothing. I want to know how to reconfigure the locale to use the new symbol by default.

Comment: I want to add indian rupee font to linux server. I dont have an font viewer. So how can I install it from terminal?